# Kubuntu 23.10, Unable to access Windows partition, mounting error

Tags: dual-boot, mount, kubuntu, windows, 23.10

Using a laptop with secure boot enabled and dual booting. I've turned off fast startup on Windows control panel and fast boot on bios, and to be sure I also deactivated PXE boot (if I'm not wrong, it is related to booting from a network, so not useful for me). The system starts as expected and everything works, (had some issues with peripherals in the beginning but was fixed after doing the above) however I get an error when trying to access the Windows partition through dolphin. Thinking of resetting Windows and reinstalling Kubuntu. Any advice is welcomed.

Error message:

> An Error occurred while accessing 'Windows', the system responded: The
> requested operation has failed: Error mounting /dev/sda3 at
> /media/silvervusly/Windows: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock
> on /dev/sda3, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Comment: Please [edit] to include the full error message

Comment: I’m wondering if your Windows partition is bitlocker encrypted?

Comment: I don't think it is. It was deactivated when I checked the control panel